# merge all txt files (including subfolders) of the location where i put the .bat

Tags: cmd

Im having a little trouble to tweak a simple script.. I have a script which i can run from cmd line but I would like to make life easier. So I would like to have a movable .bat file, which when I execute it - it merges all the txt files of the current location + sub folders:
When running the below from cmd line, its perfect, but other syntaxes for local dir doesnt seem to work

```
for /R %F in (*.txt) do if not "%~nxF"=="output.txt" type "%F" >> output.txt
```

Comment: `%~dp0` is the folder where your batch file resides.

Comment: so would be the correct file cmd:
for /R %F in (%~dp0.txt) do if not "%~nxF"=="output.txt" type "%F" >> output.txt
or? cause i have been trying some stuff and i dont want to suddenly have my whole system's txt being merged lel

Comment: I would rather do `for /R "%~dp0" %F in (*.txt) do ... >>"%~dp0output.txt"`. Remember do double the percent signs for the metavariable `%F` when you put it into a batch file: `%%F`, `%%~nxF`

Comment: when i run this i get the error "~dp0output.txt" was unexpected at this time"

Comment: also this does not work :(   for /R "%~dp0" %F in (*.txt) do if not "%~nxF"=="output.txt" type "%F" >> output.txt

Comment: Put the following line into a batchfile and run it: `for /R "%~dp0" %%F in (*.txt) do if not "%%~nxF"=="output.txt" type "%%F" >> "%~dp0output.txt"`

Comment: The issue is that you clearly do not know the difference between a command, and a script. You stated that you had "a little trouble to tweak a simple script", which you could "run from cmd line". Then you posted a command line, which you could enter within cmd.exe. That was not a script, whereas the "movable .bat file" you mentioned would have been. To modify your command line to run properly from a `.bat` script, it would look more like this `For /R %%F In (*.txt) Do If /I Not "%%~nxF" == "output.txt" Type "%%F" 1>> "output.txt"`. _That code will always be based around the current location_.

Comment: If `output.txt` was new to this command, i.e. did not already exist, it would probably be more efficient to write it like this: `(For /R %%F In (*.txt) Do If /I Not "%%~nxF" == "output.txt" Type "%%F") 1> "output.txt"`. Also if you wanted this to be based around the batch file location, as opposed to that of the current location, `%CD%`, then perhaps this would be your batch script line, `(For /R "%~dp0" %%F In (*.txt) Do If /I Not "%%~nxF" == "output.txt" Type "%%F") 1> "output.txt"`. The `/R` option allows you to choose the location to root the command from, default is the currect directory.

Comment: To find out how to use a command, you should not be asking on technical sites like this. Your first instinct should be to read the usage information for the command you are having an issue with. In this case, you should open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information presented. You can also do the same thing with `if /?`, and `type /?` too.

Comment: Stephan your last comment worked, thankyou very much! @Compo then indeed i'm mixing up the both, script & command, the thing is i just wanted to have a command put in a .bat and execute it whereever I want and have the respective results - i thought this was a script. Thank you both!

Comment: Please note @JanSchoeppen, that the example provided by Stephan was improved in my comment, I would advise that you use my version, even if the file was already existing, _in which case, `(For /R "%~dp0" %%F In (*.txt) Do If /I Not "%%~nxF" == "output.txt" Type "%%F") 1>> "%~dp0output.txt"` would still be more efficient_. The case insensitive option with the `If` command is certainly better, and should be used for extra robustness. Please note, that in this example, I redirected the `type`d content to `output.txt` in the batch file directory, as opposed to the current location.